# Google Workspace (Gmail) Desktop Notifications not working on Windows 10

Tags: google-chrome, gmail

I have set up a new Google Workspace account for my business on my own domain name to be able to use an email address (e.g. info@mycompany.com) with a Gmail account.

Everything is working fine, but the desktop notifications are not working when I receive a new email. I'm on Windows 10 and use the Chrome browser.
Anyone knows what could be the problem?

I have tried all 4 methods explained in this article: https://www.partitionwizard.com/partitionmanager/gmail-notifications-not-working.html but it is still not working. The notification sound plays when a new message is received, but the notification does not show up (I mean the small popup window that should appear in the bottom right corner of my screen).

Also, I wonder if it is possible to have these notifications show up even if my Chrome browser is not opened?

Thank you